# If $q^{n+1}$ doesn't converge, then why $\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$ doesn't converge either?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suposse $q^{n+1}$ doesn't converge (I know this happens only when $|q|\geq 1$ and $q \neq 1$ ). Then why $\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$ doesn't converge either? Should I use the definition of "no convergence" ie divergence.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}={\dfrac{1}{1-q}}\times({1-q^{n+1}})$.

If $q^{n+1}$ does not converge then $1-q^{n+1}$ also does not converge and, more generally, $a\times({1-q^{n+1}})$ also does not converge if $a$ is real number different from zero.

In your example $a=\dfrac {1}{1-q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Negation, addition of a constant ($1$) and division by a nonzero constant ($1-q$) are continuous operations on $\overline{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Taking @user236182 's suggestion,

$q^n$ diverges if and only if $q=-1$ or $|q|>1$.

i) $q>1$
$$\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}=\sum_{k=1}^n q^k > q^n$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}q^n=\infty$$

ii) $q<-1$
$$\left|\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\right|>\frac{|q^{n+1}|-|1|}{|1-q|}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}\right|\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|q^{n+1}|-|1|}{|1-q|}=\infty$$

iii) $q=-1$:
$$\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}=\sum_{k=0}^n q^k=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k=\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}$$

Therefore if $q^n$ doesn't converge, $\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$ doesn't converge either.

Comment: This argument won't work if $q=-1$.

Comment: The assumption is "If $q^n$ diverges". Ah I got your point.

Comment: $(-1)^n$ diverges.

Comment: $q=-1$ can be treated as a separate simple case. If $q<-1$, then $q^n$ gets arbitrarily large, but you can't say that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}q^n=+\infty$ in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I think the @Justpassingby 's statement is more than enough for this question.

Comment: Though you could make a little edit to make yours correct. $q^n$ diverges if and only if either $q=-1$ or $|q|>1$. $q=-1$ is a simple case, where $\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$, and if $|q|>1$, then $q^n$ gets arbitrarily large, and $q^n<\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks. I made edits.

Comment: The expression is defined if $q=-1$. It equals $0$ when $n$ is odd and $1$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: Hey, you're right :0). I fixed it.